# How to edit an Excel- Power Query Connection via VBA Macros?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am using various Excel-sheets to grab stock-sata for my stock-valuation Excel-sheets. Therefore, I have an individual Excel file per stock, which contains a power query-link to a homepage, where I grab the data shown in tables there.

After importing them into my files, I do certain calculations with this data.

I use a "master-file", which contains an VBA-macro, that opens all the individual Excel-files one after the other (I have a table there containing all folder-pathes from my files), activates the "data-grabbing" via the "established" power query, then saves the file and continues with the next one. Since I have more than 200 individual files, it is no option to open all these files manually.

My problem is, that the homepage I grab the data from, changes the names of the headers in their tables from time to time, which causes an error within power query, because the "step-lists" there refer to a specific column with a specific header name, that now doesn't exist anymore.

Example: I want to replace the "space" between the numbers with "nothing" in the colum "Sales", to make a transformation like "1 208" -> "1208" (removed the space). Therefore, I need to acress the column "Sales". When the homepage changes the name of the column to "Sales per" (or any other name), power query can't handle this and creates an error, because there is no more column "Sales", which causes my whole macro to stop.

My current way to solve this problem is to open each individual file, and "hardcode" the new column-header. This is quite time-consuming, and since I will add more and more single stock-files over the time, I need a way to automate this.

Is there any possibility to fix terms within a power-query code with a VBA-macro? I tried to record a macro for this, but no code is recorded, as long as i work within the power query editor. Maybe I can write the whole code in a textfile, and use "global variables" there, in combination with "individual variables", that are written in the individual files (I need them to adress the correct URLs).

I have a solution in mind, where I grad the "raw code" from the external text file, merge it with some "global variables" from the "master-file" and some "individual variables" from the individual files, and let it create the individual power-query code that is then used within the individual files. When one file is done, the whole process is redone with the next file.

I would like to work with variable names, that I could "globally" change via my master-file. The idea is to just once do a change within my master file, and after executing the "UpdateAllFiles"-macro, each individual files executes the power query with the changes done, so I can simply adjust changes once, and it applies to all files.

Maybe important: All files grab data from the same homepage (which makes use of variables easy to create the URL), so the URLs I adress have all the same structure, and the steps done within the Power Query code itself are also the same, but the individual power query code refers to variables that are set in the individual files. I could import them into the master-file if necessary, so I would just need to use variables from the master file.

So I need to find a way to modify only the names of the headers of the tables, leaving the rest of the code untouched.

The struture of each individual **power query task** is like this:

1. Grab Data from Table_1 from the homepage "www.[fix_part_1]/[individual_part]/fix_part_2]
2. Grab Data from Table_2 from the homepage "www.[fix_part_1]/[individual_part]/fix_part_2]
3. Merge Table_1 and Table_2
4. Import the merges tables into the individual sheet

The "master-file"-**VBA macro** does the following steps:

1. Open a file (folder path is written in a table in the master-file)
2. Refresh the power query task (-> doing steps 1) to 4) from above)
3. Insert the imported data to specific columns in the sheet
4. Do some calculations with the newly imported data
5. Save the file, close the file
6. Repeat these steps with the next file from the folder-path-table

**I need a macro, that dynamically allows me to change the power query code of multiple files, if possible**

It wasn't easy for me to express my problem, since there are so many steps that are done, and since some tasks are done within the individual files, and others globally.

I would appreciate if someone can give me some hints or code on how to fix this.

Googled the problem (not much to find)
Tried to record a Excel-macro, but this didn't allow me to adjust the settings I wanted to change

Comment: Will the number and order of columns always be consistent? And is this true for all the files?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes, the number of colums will always be the same for all files, since they come from the tables that I grab the data from. But it is possible that this amount may vary in the future, when the homepage changes its tables. So i need a dynamic solution, if possible

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery,

```
 x= Table.ColumnNames(TableNameHere)
```

will grab the column names of that table. From there you can change what you want

```
 x= Table.ColumnNames(TableNameHere){0}
```

would be the name of Column1

For example, if you hard coded Column1 that had name **Sam I Am** to remove spaces you would get

```
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{"Sam I Am", "SamIAm"}})
```

but you can instead use this to dynamically change column1

```
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{Table.ColumnNames(Source){0}, Text.Remove(Table.ColumnNames(Source){0}," ")}})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to change that with via a VBA-Macro?

Comment: Any powerquery can be generated through VBA. Thats beyond what I plan to go into here